# Changing the color of a UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) 
{       
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                          target:self
                                                                                          action:@selector(cancel)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send to Twitter"
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(save)];

}
return self;
}
```

Another piece of code

```
 - (void)loadView 
    {
[super loadView];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
textView.delegate = self;
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,0,0);
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];    
textView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self.view addSubview:textView];
}
```

I'm trying to change the navigation bar color to black, however no matter what i do here, the color still stays default (Blue).  How do you change the color of the bar on top of the view??

[image]

Comment: Wondering if you have put the navigationBar in the nib file as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;`

This should be done on `viewWillAppear:` as during `init` method `self.navigationController` will be obtained as `nil` and hence will not produce any effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're putting this line into your `initWithNibName:bundle` method, put it inside the `if` statement - any changes to `self` before then will be overwritten and lost.

Comment: If it's in the `init` method, then `self.navigationController` will be `nil`.  This should go in something like `-viewWillAppear:` or similar method.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Great Comment. I have edited Scott's answer and added what you had said into the answer. So all the users referring to this answer know where they should use this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a programatic approach (seems like you don't) you could write this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// window initialization
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] \
initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];
[[navigationController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

It works for me. Hope it helps! ;)